# Полиморфизм в классах c++

Tags: ооп, c++

В классах с++ используется полиморфизм, при помощи виртуальных методов и указателя на базовый класс. Допустим базовый класс A, производные B,C - тогда я же могу использовать вместо виртуальных методов, указатель типа void с последующим привидением типов? Суть полиморфизма не изменится!?

Пример:

```
void *ptrVoid; 
B b1; 
C c1; 
ptrVoid=(B*)&b1; 
ptrVoid=(C*)&c1; 
((C*)ptrVoid)->...
```

Если так возможно реализовать полиморфизм для чего тогда нужны виртуальные методы!?

Comment: А если информации о типах B и С в месте вызова нет?

Comment: И вообще, используйте параметрический полиморфизм (в C++ это шаблоны -- templates)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

А кто сказал, что это полиморфизм? Это какое-то непотребство.
Более того, в с++ нет методов, не говоря уже о виртуальных методах (стандарт, пункт 9.4. фраза "virtual method" в стандарте не встречается).
правильный полиморфизм заключается в том, что будет вызываться правильная функция по указателю на базовый класс, при этом не нужно знать, какой именно класс наследник скрывается за указателем.

```
class A {
   public:
     virtual void f() = 0;
}

class B: A{
   public:
     void f() {};
}

class C: A{
   public:
     void f() {};
}

A * b = new B();
A * c = new C();
b->f(); // здесь будет вызываться метод класса B
c->f(); // здесь будет вызываться метод класса C
```

Вы скажете, м, я могу сделать приведение. Но при этом придется хранить где то информацию о типе класса. И все превращается в такое мессиво

```
class A {
   public:
     void f(){ std::cout << "abstract virtual methot was called" << std::endl;}
     int type;
     A() {type = 1;}
}

class B: A{
   public:
     void f() {};
     B() {type = 2;}
}

class C: A{
   public:
     void f() {};
     C() {type = 3;}
}

void callF(A* x) {
  switch (x->type) {
    1:
      x->f();
      break;
    2:
      (B*)x->f();
       break;
    3:
      (C*)x->f();
       break;
    default:
      std::cout << "unknown type " << x->type << std::endl;
  }
}
A * b = new B();
A * c = new C();
callF(b);
callF(c); // здесь будет вызываться метод класса C
```

И это (если только я не сделал ошибок), будет работать. Более того, в принципе оно в реальном коде так и происходит. Но компилятор просто обладает большей информацией о ситуации в коде. К примеру Java компилятор может сделать не `switch`, а обычный `if`, если видит, что там всего два варианта. Либо вообще сделать явный вызов, если и так понятно, что вызывать.

Стоит ли так писать код? Если код пишется на Си, тогда да (более того, некоторые Си программисты почти так и пишут иногда код). Этим занимаются (немного в другом виде, правда), когда пишут на Gtk.

Стоит ли так писать в С++ коде? нет. зачем делать то, что делает компилятор? зачем делать закат Солнца вручную?

Но если кажется, что нужно делать полиморфизм по своему, то может быть нужно выбрать другой языка программирование?

**upd**

Почему следует использовать полиморфимз.

- пример 1. Пусть есть игра (starcraft, козаки, и подобные). Создается класс "базовый юнит". От него наследуются все юниты. Все созданные юниты добавляются в один большой массив (вектор, список). Когда нужно отрисовать, то просто в цикле вызываем у всех функция draw и не думаем, а кто у нас там. Каждый объект и так знает, как ему рисоваться.
- пример 2. мессенджер типа миранда или квип. Есть куча различных сервисов (аська, жаббер, мейлру). У всех есть контакт лист. Сам мессенджер ничего не знает о сервисах, он просто вызывает функции, а за счет виртуальности и полиморфизма вызываются правильные функции. При этом, если был добавлен новый сервис, то не нужно переписывать весь код, что бы он был в курсе.

Comment: Всё равно не пойму изюминку полиморфизма, я же могу просто создать два объекта и пользоваться ими на здоровье!?

    B b;
    C c;
    b.f();
    c.f();

Comment: можете. разрешаю:)

Comment: @KoVadim: +1 за закат солнца вручную :)

Comment: @KoVadim  "Но при этом придется хранить где то информацию о типе класса." Не в порядке наезда -- а RTTI куда-то исчез? `typeid`, `type_info`...

Comment: @alexlz: если я не ошибаюсь, RTTI работает только если есть виртуальные функции :-P

Comment: Ну букварь говорит, что для классов без virtual значение подставляется при компиляции. Но, увы, на значение `void *` компилятор смертельно обижается.

Comment: @KoVadim А как по вашему (по стадарту с++) называются методы и атрибуты класса?

Comment: я писал. "методы" это функции класса (member functions, 9.3). Атрибутов нет в с++ (если я правильно понимаю то, что Вы имеете ввиду). Правда в vs с++ есть расширения. Но может имеете ввиду "data member" (9.2).

Конечно, в большинстве случаев Вас поймут, когда Вы напишите "метод", но могут и посчитать невежей.

Answer (score 6):

Да, без полиморфизма можно обойтись и делать dispatch вручную. Нет, в 2013 году так никто не делает*, потому что изобретать велосипед всем надоело, и лучше заставить компилятор делать то, где вы вполне можете ошибиться.

Смысл полиморфизма как раз и заключается в том, что вам **не нужно** делать cast и знать runtime-тип объекта с потенциальной возможностью ошибиться. С полиморфизмом, вы просто вызываете метод, и отрабатывает то, что нужно, без вашего ручного управления.

Если у вас всего два-три объекта, вы можете вполне обойтись парочкой if'ов, проблем нет.

Но если у вас тысячи объектов, которые приходят из других частей программы, вам придётся либо пользоваться виртуальными методами, либо перед каждым вызовом делать огромный switch, в котором вы проверяете тип объекта.

Пример: у вас есть 10 различных классов, наследованных от общего предка. У предка есть метод `зафигачить(int сколькоРаз)`. Вам нужно для всех этих объектов вызвать `зафигачить(номерОбъекта)`. Как это сделать? Без полиморфизма ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectPointers.size(); i++)
{
    Base* pBase = objectPointers[i];
    switch (pbase->type)
    {
    case TYPE_CLASS1:
        {
            Class1* pClass1 = static_cast<Class1*>(pBase);
            pClass1->зафигачить(i);
        }
        break;
    case TYPE_CLASS2:
        {
            Class2* pClass2 = static_cast<Class2*>(pBase);
            pClass2->зафигачить(i);
        }
        break;
    // и т. д.
    }
}
```

С полиморфизмом вы вполне можете обойтись таким кодом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectPointers.size(); i++)
{
    objectPointers[i]->зафигачить(i);
}
```

Согласитесь, легче в понимании и поддержке. :)

---

*за исключением редких случаев, когда пишут на самом деле на C, а не C++

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

class B : public A{
public:
    int f(){
        cout << "+" << endl;

        return 0;
    }
};

class C : public A{
public:
    int f(){
        cout << "-" << endl;

        return 0;
    }
};

int main(){
    B b;
    C c;
    // твой вариант
    void * p;
    p = (B*)&b;
    ((B*)p)->f();

    // вариант с виртуальным наследованием выглядит как то логичней и тратится меньше процессорного времени на преобразование.
    A * a;
    a = &b;
  a->f();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то вспомнился вопрос уровня "зачем нужны классы в PHP". Правильный ответ, устраивающий задающего: "они нигде нахрен не нужны". Полиморфизм в том числе. Всё можно сделать и без этого.

А вот когда код разрастётся до продакшн, и над ним будут работать программисты, да в команде (а не пыхаперы наколенные) вот тогда вопрос отпадёт сам собой :)

Comment: Ну классы в php нужны, поскольку это модно и гламурно. А вот "код разрастётся до продакшн" -- это когда HelloWorld будет длиной в несколько сотен строк? Или тысяч?