# виртуальная перегрузка оператора в специализации шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, полиморфизм

Всем привет.

есть базовый класс:

```
class ItemBase{
    virtual operator TimePoint () const
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
}
```

есть наследники:

```
template<class Policy>
class Item<TimePoint, Policy>: public ItemBase
{
    operator TimePoint()const override
    {
        return val;
    }
private:
    TimePoint val;
}
```

Есть класс который это все использует:

```
class LineBase
{
public:
    TimePoint getTime()const{ //вот тут происходят чудеса
        return (TimePoint)items[timeIndex];
    }
protected:
    void AddItem(ItemBase &item)
    {
        items.push_back(item);
    }
    vector<ItemBase> items;
}
```

что я делаю:

```
Item<TimePoint, Items::NoPolicy> timeItem(Feilds[0]);
SetTimeIndex(0);
AddItem(timeItem);
getTime();
```

создаю специализированный итем для хранения типа TimePoint.
кладу его в вектор по базовому классу.
в базовом классе виртуально перегружены операторы приведения к типу шаблона.
в них только исключения.
в шаблоне-наследнике они override(не знаю как по русски).
потом достаю из вектора итем по базовому классу и привожу его к типу TimePoint.
при приведении вызывается перегруженный оператор базового класса, а не новая реализация в шаблоне наследнике.
подскажите пожалуйста, почему так ?

Comment: а что такое `items` у вас?

Comment: ой, точно, не то написал. поправил. это vector<ItemBase> items;

Comment: @VladD есть идеи ?

Comment: В классе LineBase у вас статичный вектор элементов ItemBase, метод AddItem работает со ссылками на ItemBase, а дальше вы передаете в него тип Item (тут по идее должна быть ошибка при компиляции или уб). P.S. я может отстал от жизни, но что это за синтаксис? `template<class Policy>
class Item<TimePoint, Policy>: public ItemBase` вроде вы объявляете класс, но сразу же пытаетесь его специализировать?

Comment: @goldstar_labs да вроде никакой он не статичный. обычный член класса. да, все верно работаю через базовый класс. но операторы то виртуальные. тут все ровно.  ну я не стал приводить все специализации. многа букф ) привел одну, как пример. это частичная специализация.

Comment: по текущем кускам кода не видно чтобы где-то использовался полиморфизм и динамически создавались экземпляры пронаследованных классов. видно что вы пытаетесь запихнуть Item по ссылке в вектор ItemBase

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/192522/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-c

Comment: @goldstar_labs что то у нас с вами не конструктивный диалог пошел.

Comment: 1) template<class Policy> class Item<TimePoint, Policy>: public ItemBase - очень странный синтаксис. Мы с компилятором его не понимаем. Какой-то странный способ задать специализацию? 2) Чтобы вам помочь, очень не хватает кода (блок "что я делаю") выглядит выдернутым из контекста. Восстановить контекст по текстовому комментарию очень сложно. Для кого это всё вызывается? Что такой Filelds и как он заполнятся? Что такое SetTimeIndex()? Что будет если вызвать Fields[0]() ( - скорее всего проблема где-то тут, не в остальной обёртке)